# How many days would it take this to happen, starting from the day she first put her sandwich in her locker?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sandy decided to do an experiment with a sandwich she left in her locker. She found it 3 days after she had put it there, took it to the lab, and counted 41 bacteria. 2 days later she counted 153 bacteria. She estimates that it will take 400 bacteria to completely cover her sandwich.

Comment: According to what mathematical model do the bacteria grow?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I assume, like most experiments of this sort, it should be an exponential increase. Am I assuming right?

Comment: yes you are right, it is an exponential increase

Comment: that graph wasn't given to my group members and I

Comment: we are planning to create one using everyone's feedback

Comment: I am assuming the answer should be day $7$. Is it right?

Comment: We are not sure if it's 7 or not

Comment: there should be a formula that describes bacteria's growth or enough data points to interpolate. two data points is not enough

Comment: Check this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421463/interpolation-of-bacteria-growth?rq=1

Comment: we must create the formula

Comment: Vasya, we checked that link already, our teacher wants the equation to be more simple

Comment: try $f(t)=5.695e^{0.658t}$, $t$ - number of days

Comment: our formula needs to be at a 10th or 11th grade level

Comment: Is my one right?

Comment: @bluewaffle I am a tenth grader myself so my answer should be easy to understand.

Comment: I checked with my group, it is incorrect @MohammadZuhairKhan

Comment: Is Vasya's answer right?

Comment: we are seniors, we are supposed to answer this question to jog our memories from freshman year, unfortunately non of us remember how to do this.

Comment: @bluewaffle what is the correct answer?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I am waiting for them to reply

Comment: According to my graph, it should be more than $6$ days and less than $7$ days.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan  it is incorrect as well we plugged in the numbers

Comment: I plugged in $x=3$ and $x=5$ and got _exactly_ $41$ and $153$. Could you respond on why my answer is wrong?

Comment: And Vasya's approximate formula produced nearly $41$ and $153$ when $t=3$ and $t=5$ respectively.

Comment: Vasya's function graphed is almost like mine: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sb2cqoeong

Comment: And they all happily live ever after.

Comment: If we assume a sandwich with side length of ten centimeters a bacteria’s diameter will be about  five millimeter, provided that four hundred of them fill the sandwich.  So Sandy discovered a biological revolution.

Comment: It was a really tiny sandwich.  And sandy has really good eyes and can count bacteria one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming exponential growth, we are looking for a solution in form of $f(t)=Ce^{kt}$. Since $f(3)=41$ and $f(5)=153$, it's easy to find $k$: $$e^{2k}=153/41$$ $k=0.5\ln{\frac{153}{41}}\approx 0.658$. Now let's find $C$: $$Ce^{0.658\cdot 5}=153$$
or $C\approx5.7$. The final formula is $f(t)=5.7e^{0.658t}$

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
I am assuming this to be a geometric series.

$T_3 = 41 = ar^2$
$T_5 = 153 = ar^4$

$\therefore r^2 = \frac {T_5}{T_3}= \frac {153}{41}$

$\therefore r = \sqrt \frac {153}{41}$

$a = \frac{41}{\frac {153}{41}} = \frac{1681}{153}$.

So you get the equation $400 = \frac{1681}{153}*(\sqrt \frac {153}{41})^{n-1}$
 where $n$ is the number of days that have elapsed. I assume I have provided a simpler (perhaps even wrong) answer. You can easily plot the graph of $y = \frac{1681}{153}*(\sqrt \frac {153}{41})^{x-1}$ and find the value of $x$ when $y=400$.

**Bonus:**

Here is the graph:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ma9jeubfks

Answer (score 0):

As the objects nearly quadruple in two days from $41$ to $153$, they will nearly double in one day. So after one more day we expect a bit less than three hundred ($2\times 153$) and after two more days about six hundert species.  Hence seven days from start they will have reached a population of four hundred, final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expected to parrot a bunch of formulas or are you supposed to think.

In 3 to 5 days bacteria increased form $43$ to $153$ or in other words they grew $\frac {153}{43}$ times in 2 days.  So two days, after  seven days,that they will grow another $\frac {153}{43}$ times and there will be $153*\frac {153}{43}=544$ so it will occur sometime before them.  Somewhere between the sixth and seventh day.

If $P_0$ was the number of bacteria on the sandwich when she put it in the locker and $r$ is the rate at which the bacteria grow in a day.

Then $P(t) = P_0*r^t$ are the number of bacteria after $t$ days.

So we have $P(3) = P_0*r^3 = 43$ and $P(5) = P_0*r^5 = 153$.

So $\frac {153}{43} = \frac {P_0*r^5}{P_0*r^3} = r^2$ so $r = \sqrt{\frac {153}{43}}$

And so $P_0*\sqrt{\frac {153}{43}}^3 = 43$ we have $P_0 = \frac {43}{\sqrt{\frac {153}{43}}^3}$.

So we need to solve for $P(t) = \frac {43}{\sqrt{\frac {153}{43}}^3}* \sqrt{\frac {153}{43}}^t = 400$.

So $\sqrt{\frac {153}{43}}^t=\frac{400}{\frac {43}{\sqrt{\frac {153}{43}}^3}}$

So $t = \log_{\sqrt{\frac {153}{43}}}( \frac{400}{\frac {43}{\sqrt{\frac {153}{43}}^3}})$

That's the answer.

.. Um,  You're welcome????

.....

Bearing in mind that $r^t = (e^{\ln r})^t = e^{\ln r t}$ it is more conveinient to write the population formula as

$P(t) = P_0*e^kt$ where $k = \ln r$

In this case $\ln \sqrt{\frac {153}{43}} \approx  0.63462$.

$P_0 =  \frac {43}{\sqrt{\frac {153}{43}}^3}\approx 6.407$

So the formula for $P(t) = 6.407*e^{.63462 t}$

So we want $P(t) =   6.407*e^{.63462 t} = 400$ so ($400$ bacteria?  That is one *tiny* sandwich!!!!!!  Or really *huge* bacteria... which consider she can *count* them one by one is ... wierd.)

$e^{.63462 t} = \frac {400}{6.407}$

$.63462 t = \ln (\frac {400}{6.407})$

$t = \frac {\ln (\frac {400}{6.407})}{.63462} = 6.514$